# Vim indenting and alignment: combining spaces and tabs

Tags: vim, editor, tabs, whitespace, indentation

I'm trying to work out how to get Vim to follow a slightly more complex indentation scheme than most editors allow by default. Essentially I want to use tabs for indentation, but spaces to align statements that span more than one line. For example:

```
    private static $_columns = array('id' => 'id',
                                     'email' => 'email',
                                     'passwordHash' => 'password_hash',
                                     'salt' => 'salt');
    ^ tabs up to here
                                     ^ spaces up to here
```

The idea here is that indentation follows the tab-width preferences of whoever is editing the file, while multi-line statements still align correctly.

I guess the simple way to implement this would be to have Vim just copy the indentation pattern used on the previous line (i.e. the leading white space) whenever a new line is entered. Is there any way to do this in Vim? Would I need to write a plugin?

Comment: @sidyll: Not quite as neat, and requires more effort! Still, I've never played with modelines before, so I'll go and experiment – thanks!

Comment: I agree. I just suggested it as, in some cases, when you *know* that the receiver will read the file in Vim, a simple `vim:ts=4` works nicely.

Answer (score 6):

There is a wikia entry dedicated to that topic : [Indent with tabs, align with spaces](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indent_with_tabs,_align_with_spaces)

The suggested solution is to use a plugin : "[Smart Tabs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=231)"

Comment: This seems like exactly the thing I want, but it doesn't seem to work. I've put it in my Pathogen `bundle` directory but if I take the snippet posted above and add a line, it just uses tabs as normal and pads them out with spaces. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Will Vousden : I don't use that plugin myself, so I can't really comment on it. What feature you were expecting is missing ?

Comment: Well I think the problem I was having at first was caused by another plugin, but it still seems kind of erratic. For example, if I press enter in insert mode at the end of the second line in my example, the alignment spaces are replaced by a single tab, and the new line is also indented by a single tab. It seems to work sporadically when using `o` and `O` for new lines, but not for `cc`. I guess the reason is that it's just using mappings to emulate different autoindent behaviour, which is a less-than-perfect implementation?

Comment: Ideally it should work at a lower level in any situation where autoindent is triggered and actually replace the default autoindent rather than just correct it, but perhaps that's just not possible?